# Jquery notification event firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, gritter

I have just started using gritter notification plugin and experiencing strange behavior. I am displaying the notification on page load and for some reason, the same message is appearing twice. I would be grateful if someone could check my code and highlight any errors that I have overlooked. The link for the plugin is: http://boedesign.com/blog/2009/07/11/growl-for-jquery-gritter/. Many thanks.

**UPDATED HTML FROM FIREBUG**

```
<div id="gritter-notice-wrapper">

    <div id="gritter-item-2" class="gritter-item-wrapper" role="alert" style="">
        <div class="gritter-top"></div>
        <div class="gritter-item">
            <a class="gritter-close" tabindex="1" href="#" style="display: none;">

                Close Notification

            </a>
            <div class="gritter-without-image">
                <span class="gritter-title">

                    New Message

                </span>
                <p>

                    You have  

                    <span class="yourstyle">

                        1

                    </span>

                     new message(s). Please go to the message area in …

                </p>
            </div>
            <div style="clear:both"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="gritter-bottom"></div>
    </div>


    <div id="gritter-item-3" class="gritter-item-wrapper" role="alert" style="">
        <div class="gritter-top"></div>
        <div class="gritter-item">
            <a class="gritter-close" tabindex="1" href="#">

                Close Notification

            </a>
            <div class="gritter-without-image">
                <span class="gritter-title">

                    New Message

                </span>
                <p>

                    You have  

                    <span class="yourstyle">

                        1

                    </span>

                     new message(s). Please go to the message area in …

                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="gritter-bottom"></div>
    </div>

</div>  


<div id="messages" style="float: left;height: 220px">
     <div>
       Messages
     </div>
     <div style="overflow: hidden;">
        <div id="message"style="font-size: 11px; padding: 10px 10px;" >

            <?php

                mysql_select_db($database_domain, $domain); 
                $query1 = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE to_user = '$_SESSION[kt_name_usr]' AND `read` = 1"; 
                $result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die(mysql_error());
                $totalRows1 = mysql_num_rows($result1);
                if (mysql_num_rows($result1) ==0) {
                $error1 = true;
                $message3 = "You have no new messages.";
                } else {
                // There was a result
                // now check if there were any records.
                    if (mysql_num_rows($result1) >0) {    
                        $error1 = false;
                        $messages1 = "You have" . "  " . "<span class='yourstyle'>" . $totalRows1 . "</span>" . " " . "new message(s). Please go to the message area in your control panel."; 
                  }
                 } 

                 if($error1 == 0)  {

                    echo "You have" . "  " . "<span class='yourstyle'>" . $totalRows1 . "</span>" . " " . "new message(s). Please go to the message area in your control panel.";

                    echo "<SCRIPT type=text/javascript>\n";
                    echo "$(function() {\n";
                    echo "$(\"#testid\" ).show()\n";
                    echo "$.gritter.add({title: 'This is a notice', text: \"".$messages1."\"})\n";
                    echo "});\n";
                    echo "</script>\n";

                } else { 

                    echo 'There are no new system or site messages to display.';

                }

             ?>

            </div>

           </div>

          </div>

          <div id="testid" style="display:none;"></div>
```

**SOLUTION:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(function () {
            var newmsg = <?php echo json_encode($messages1) ?>;
            $.gritter.add({title: 'New Message', text: newmsg, time: 4000, sticky: false});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't find any notification on page load. Perhaps you could provide a fiddle?

Comment: @theScorpion fiddle does not accept php mark up. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out this line,

```
echo "You have" . "  " . "<span class='yourstyle'>" . $totalRows1 . "</span>" . " " . "new message(s). Please go to the message area in your control panel.";
```

Comment: Hi Apul. Still the same. Firing twice. Thanks

Comment: Please share page's view source rendered in browser.

Comment: <div id="messages" style="float: left;height: 220px">
                    <div>
                        Messages
                    </div>
                    <div style="overflow: hidden;">
   <div id="message" style="font-size: 11px; padding: 10px 10px;">
       
   <script type=text/javascript>
$.gritter.add({title: 'This is a new notice', text: "You have  <span class='yourstyle'>1</span> new message(s). Please go to the message area in your control panel.", time: 3000});
</script>
      
   </div>
                        
                    </div>
                </div>

Comment: there should be some js/css also. I need full html code generated after execution. If this is a response of ajax, share the initiator page html code with me.

Comment: If i right click view source in ff, I can the markup of the code. What exasctly should I be looking for. css/js is available from the link I posted. Also, has a thought. Could it be it is bubbling and I perhaps need to stoppropogation? Thanks

Comment: would be nice if you can share url where did u implement this. This type of issues come when two times same event getting bind.

Comment: I do notice though from innerHTML that it is appearing twice. I shall post html that appears in firebug. Thanks

Comment: Turned out to be quite simple. Deleted original script and declared new script to before </body> tag. Works well. Shall post my code in original question so it may benefit others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue resolved by stopImmediatePropagation()

try to use following code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       $(function (event) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            var newmsg = <?php echo json_encode($messages1) ?>;
            $.gritter.add({title: 'New Message', text: newmsg, time: 4000, sticky: false});
    });
</script>
```